# List distribution group membership in OWA for group in group

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

If I as a user want to check to which distribution groups I am currently added, I use OWA. There I can click on Groups and get two lists:

- Public Groups I Belong To
- Public Groups I Own

Let's say I have a distribution group called Development and I am not a direct member of this group. I am a member of the right group devteam-eagle. Now, this group is added as member in the Development distribution group. This makes me a (ok, not direct) member of the group, too. But I can't see it in OWA. Is there a way to get those groups listed as well?

Comment: What API are you sing? Outlook Object Model? EWS? MAPI?

Comment: I was using OWA(EWS)